# Physical memory access from Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

From softirq context, I need to access physical memory (size is 16MB - yeah, it is huge) region and dump those memory regions to flash.

This is for "firmware crashdump" and firmware will DMA core file to that DRAM region.

So, I am going to use ioremap, read and write to flash. Is it really crazy idea? Is there any practical example which I can refer?

or should I use phys_to_virt and then access the memory region?

I am very new to this kind of work. Please understand stupid question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, can I use "memcpy" to copy those contents to the buffer?

Comment: yes you have to use ioremap kernel calls to map the phy region to virtual region.

Comment: You need to do the mapping outside of softirq context, but you can access the mapped memory from softirq context. Since you want to DMA into the area, you should probably use `dma_alloc_coherent` to allocate it.